# C Read TXT File 24 lines

Tags: c

I'm new to c. i have a problem please help me
I am reading from the file. But I want to read the file 24 lines first and I want to ask the user, okay or not?
if the user wants to continue I will read 24 more lines

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char const* const fileName = argv[1];
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
char line[256];
int i=0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    for(i=0;i<24;i++){
        printf("%s", line); 
        i++;
    }

}

fclose(file);

return 0;
```

I wrote something like this, I'm sure it's not right, help me

Comment: You should do `argv[1]` only after checking `argc`.

Comment: you are updating ``i`` twice in for loop and at foor loop

Comment: Your loops doesn't actually do what you've intended to do.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], sample input (both file and user input), describe what makes you think that something is wrong, describe the difference to what you want to achieve and describe what you did to debug.

Comment: Can you give an example of how should I update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the command line first:

```
if(argc < 2) {
   printf("usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
   return -1;
}
```

You should check the `fopen` also:

```
if(!file) {
   printf("cannot open %s\n", filename);
   return -1;
}
```

In the code of `while` loop, you have a mistake. You are updating i twice (one in for statement, another in the `for` loop), you should remove one:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    for(i=0;i<24;i++){ // first update here
        printf("%s", line); 
        i++; // second update here
    }
}
```

For asking the user each 24 times of reading, you can compare the module `i%24` with `0`. The `while` loop can be as below:

```
    char ch = 'y'; // if ch is not equal to 'y', we quit the loop and stop reading file
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) && ch == 'y') {
        printf("%s", line); 
        i++;
        if(i%24 == 0) { // ask the user after each time of reading 24 line
            printf(" i = %d Do you want to continue(y/n): ", i); // type y or Y to continue, type another to stop reading
            scanf(" %c",&ch);
            ch = tolower(ch); 
        }
    }
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!file) {
        printf("cannot open %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    char line[256];
    int i = 0;
    char ch = 'y';
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) && ch == 'y') {
        printf("%s", line); 
        i++;
        if(i%24 == 0) {
            printf("Do you want to continue (y/n): ");
            scanf(" %c",&ch);
            ch = tolower(ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some analysis of the code you posted and in the other half I have tried to provide solution, see if it works for you -

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char const* const fileName = argv[1];
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");  // Check if fileName is valid(not NULL)
char line[256]; // use 'memset' to initialize 'line'.
int i=0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    // You print a line like this when you want to print 'char by char'
    // you already have a 'line' just use printf("%s", line)
    for(i=0;i<24;i++){
        printf("%s", line); 
        i++;
    }

}

fclose(file);

return 0;
} // this was missing.
```

Solution -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char const* const fileName = argv[1];
char line[256];
size_t read_size = 24;
char ok;

if (!fileName)
    return printf("Invalid filename!\n");

FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
while (fgets(line, read_size, file)) {
        printf("line = %s\n", line);
        printf("y/n ? : ");
        ok = getchar();
        if (ok == 'n')
                break;
}

fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```